# Do battlerager fighters gain extra temporary hit points from hitting with invigorating powers?

Tags: dnd-4e, temporary-hit-points

`Battlerager` fighters gain temporary hit points from hitting with melee and close attacks, "plus any temporary hit points normally granted by the power" (exact words used in the compendium).

The `Invigorating` keyword is defined such that when a character trained in endurance hits with an invigorating power, they gain temporary hit points.

So, are the temporary hit points granted by the combination of the invigorating keyword on the power, and the character being skilled in `Endurance` "temporary hit points normally granted by the power"?

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the errata.  The important point there being the hit points don't stack.  This was kind of a big issue in our campaign.

Comment: Wait, so are you asking if a fighter, not trained in endurance would get the temp hp from the battlerager power?  If so I'd say yes... you wouldn't get the invigorating temp hp of course but the power is still has the keyword even if you don't qualify for the bonus.

Comment: No was was asking about the temporary hit points granted by the combination of endurance and the invigorating keyword, and how they interact with the temporary hit points granted from the Battlerager vigor class feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**, Battleragers get to double dip on the invigorating powers.

Invigorating<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=94)</sup> is defined on p7 of the Martial Power book.

Here is a [link](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19686342/Rules_Q38;A_FAQ__ask_a_simple_question?post_id=464084849#464084849) to the same question (and some related ones) on the wizards board.

This simple table tells you how many temp hp you receive.  (Assuming a Battlerager with Endurance)

```
Power type        Hit     Miss
------------------------------
Invigorating     2xCon    Con
Regular           Con      0
```

Temporary HP do not stack.  If you gain THP (Temporary Hit Points) and currently have THP, then retain only the highest number of THP.

Comment: Is that based on an expectation on how the rules should work? Or on interpreting invigorating temp hp as being a "normally granted by the power", or from another rule or ruling?

Comment: Yes, invigorating powers normally grant temp hp.  That is the  function of the invigorating keyword.